# python3 urllib request returning filename with special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, urllib

I am running this query to retrieve a file:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename_variable)
```

this works however returns the file name with special characters E.G
"file.tar.gz?"

If I try to run by specify the filename without a variable e.g

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,"filename.tar.gz")
```

this works.

So the question is how can I resolve the issue with file being returned with special characters when passing a variable to query?

Comment: You should define the filename (where to store the page pointed by the URL). Python doen't modify function arguments.It is your task to find a valid filename, so that your operating system can create such file. Special characters are fine, if they are not `/` or `\` or `:` or `\0`, according various operating systems.

Comment: What do you mean by "special character"? Non-ASCII Unicode? And I assume you forget quotes in `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "filename.tar.gz")`

Comment: @ascripter yes sorry urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "filename.tar.gz") this is how I am using it. yes i believe they might be Non-ASCII unicode however looking at some resources i can see that everything is unicode automatically python3. so I am not sure how I am having this issue

Comment: my aim is to get this working with a variable instead of "filename.tar.gz" so that i can resuse the code